# What information would I need to calculate proper placement of my Unity 3D orthographic HUD elements?

Tags: unity, camera

I have a Unity project and I have managed to create a 3D HUD by creating a separate (orthographic) camera for rendering elements on the UI layer.  I already have some objects appearing in the HUD and rendering correctly.

What I want to do now is calculate the proper position and scale of these elements to make sure they are in the upper left corner and only take up 60% of the vertical space.

I am optimistic the necessary information is available to C# script components, but I have no idea which formulas and which members or methods (probably on the Camera object) can tell me what the X/Y bounds of the orthographic view are (for whatever the current aspect ratio is).

Answer (score 1):

Use the new UI.  Add the 3D object to the canvas, make sure the canvas is in Screen Space or World Space.

Some screenshots from a [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1282715/render-a-3d-object-in-a-2d-ui-panel.html) post about this very problem.

[image: Game view]
[image: Scene view]

Once you do that, you can use the RectTransform and Gui Layout features that exist to place UI elements where you want them on screen, regardless of the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `orthographicSize` and `aspect` properties of the camera like so:

```
public class HUDManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera HUDCamera;
...
    void Start() {
...
        float x = - ( HUDCamera.orthographicSize * HUDCamera.aspect -tileWidth/2);
        float y0 = HUDCamera.orthographicSize - tileHeight/2;
...
            line.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y0 - i*tileHeight*1.1f, 0);
```

I am unsure if this would malfunction if the game screen were tall instead of wide.